# Symfony 3 — ACL parent/child relation

Tags: inheritance, acl, symfony

I am about to checkout/evaluate the ACL features of Symphony3. Even if everybody recommends to use a voter, I am not sure if it will fit my needs, so I decided to dig a bit deeper that topic. As I found in Source and in the [API-Documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Domain/Acl.html) there are two methods I came over:

```
    getParentAcl()
    setParentAcl(AclInterface $acl = null)
```

Are these methods meant to create hierarchies of permissions, or do they exist for another purpose?

What I would like to have is something is a »tree of permissions« like that:

```
+ registered User [VIEW, VOTE]
|
+-+ authorized User (level 1) [FLAG, UN- and PUBLISH]
  |
  + authorized User (level 2) [EDIT, DELETE]
```

so that the permissions sum up from parent to child. From the example above an »authorized User (level 2)« should have all permissions (VIEW, VOTE, FLAG, …, DELETE).

All in all: The Idea is to assign certain Permissions to a Role, which can inherit from each other, and use the [RoleSecurityIdentity](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Security/Acl/Domain/RoleSecurityIdentity.html) to assign the Permissions on class Level.

Is symfony3's ACL parent/child relation meant to do such things?

I appreciate any Help and would be happy about some detailed documentation!

Thanks in Ahead!

Comment: CakePHP's ACL has roles/users hierarchies https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html I am also looking for something similar for Symfony

Answer (score 0):

> The PermissionGrantingStrategy first checks all your object-scope ACEs. If none is applicable, the class-scope ACEs will be checked. If none is applicable, then the process will be repeated with the ACEs of the parent ACL. If no parent ACL exists, an exception will be thrown.
>   [Process for Reaching Authorization Decisions](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/acl_advanced.html#process-for-reaching-authorization-decisions)